# Does Dutch residence permit apply to EU citizens?

Tags: resident-permit, netherlands, eu-citizens

I see lots of questions alluding to the Dutch concept of *verblijfsvergunning*, which my 2003 Dutch language textbook says is required to buy a house in the Netherlands if you’re from another country.

If the “[Single European Market stands for ‘free movement’ of people, goods, services and capital](https://web.archive.org/web/20071001122551/http://ec.europa.eu/internal_market/index_en.htm),” can such a thing be still required of EU citizens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such things aren't required of EU citizens.  Your 2003 Dutch textbook was written before [Directive 2004/38/EC](https://eur-lex.europa.eu/legal-content/EN/TXT/?uri=CELEX:02004L0038-20110616) was enacted, and the law in the Netherlands was different then.  I was living in Amsterdam at the time, and I had an English colleague who was stopped by a police officer for crossing the street away from a pedestrian crossing and told that he had to go get a residence permit.

That requirement was removed somewhat later, presumably because of directive 2004/38/EC.

Comment: Thanks.  I thought the "free movement" part was in place longer than that.

Comment: @WGroleau In a different form it did exist. This directive formulised it in a more comprehensive manor. **It consolidated older regulations and directives**

Comment: @WGroleau Mainly directive (EWG) Nr. 1612/68.. In Germany a residence permit was issued stating that in all matters concerning working the same rights as German citizens applid. https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aufenthaltserlaubnis_(Deutschland)#Entwicklungen_zwischen_1945_und_1990

Comment: @WGroleau as Mark Johnson says, the directive consolidated various aspects of free movement.  Free movement of workers, for example, had been in place for decades, but freedom for the self-sufficient to relocate was not.  The directive also established the principle that residence permits could not be required.